# Set / Read part of a cookie

Tags: jquery

I'm using this cookie plugin for reference: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Is it possible to read and set part of a cookie.

If I was to set the following cookie initially.

```
$.cookie('CookieName', 'A1-B1-C1-D1-E1-F1', { expires: 1, path: '/'});
```

Is it possible to only check the string for "B1", ignoring the rest of the cookie, then:

```
If B1 do X
Else if B2 do Y
```

In the same way, would it be possible to only change one of the values, changing "A1" to "A2" leaving the rest of the string the same.

Reason for this is I'd like to try condense cookies that do similar actions instead of an individual cookie for each one.

Comment: You would read the cookie and the parse the value to determine if it contained what you wanted it to contain.

Comment: See @roasted response - he shows you how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Cookie can only save string, so you have to code some logic regarding string manipulation, e.g:

{split use zero indexed value: [0] first, [1] second, etc...}

```
if($.cookie('CookieName').split('-')[1] === "B1")
   //do stuff
else ($.cookie('CookieName').split('-')[1] === "B2")
   //do other stuff
```

Comment: Could you explain this further?

Comment: He split the string contained in the cookie value. Splitting creates an array that he tests against in the if statement.